# How to store data to database in LARAVEL 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Iam beginer on Laravel, i have problem when i want to store data to database.
When name on view different with field name on database data didn't save on database but when input name on view same with field name on database data stored correctly

example
this is view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Job</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="job" placeholder="Job">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label>Machine</label>
            {{ Form::select('machine', $mesin_laminating->pluck('active', 'kode')->all(), null, ['class' => 'form-control select2'])}}                                      
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

this is my controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'job' => 'required',
        'machine' => 'required'
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();
    SpkAdmin::create($input);

}
```

this is my model

```
protected $table = 'tb_job';

protected $fillable = ['user_job', 'machine'];
```

this is my database

```
user_job | machine
------   | ------
Cell     | Cell
```

How to scyn job on controller to store on user_job? 
Sorry for my english

Comment: You want form field names different than in DB ?

Comment: @GaneshGhalame i want input name different with field name in DB

Comment: If answer works approve and upvote it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace `store` as below:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'job' => 'required',
        'machine' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    $spkAdmin = new SpkAdmin();
    //On left field name in DB and on right field name in Form/view/request
    $spkAdmin->user_job = $request->input('job');
    $spkAdmin->machine = $request->input('machine');
    $spkAdmin->save();
}
```

Comment: i have error when i do that, error on - $spkAdmin = SpkAdmin::new SpkAdmin();

Comment: removed `SpkAdmin::` in object creation my mistake updated code check now

Comment: Undefined variable: spkAmin || where query for inputing to model (DB) ?

Comment: its typo check now

Answer (score 4):

there is another way of adding data in database something like this

```
$data = Input::all();    
$check = DB::table('tablename')->insertGetId(array(
                                                'phone_no'      => $data['number'],
                                                'firstname'     => $data['first_name'],
                                                'lastname'      => $data['last_name'],
                                                'birth_month'   => $data['birth_month'],
                                                'birth_year'    => $data['birth_year'],
                                                'zipcode'       => $data['zip_code'],
                                                'device_token'  => $data['device_token'],
                                                'created_at' => Carbon::now()
                                                        ));
```

hope this could solve your query

Comment: Your query didnt need model ?

Comment: no it's not because it's a alternative method for insert data

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\SpkAdmin;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request->all(), [
        'job' => 'required',
        'machine' => 'required'
    ]);

$spkAdmin = SpkAdmin::create($request->all());

    Or 

$input = [];
$input = $request->all();
$input['user_job'] = $request->get('job');
$input['machine'] = $request->get('machine');
SpkAdmin::create($input);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).