# How do I store a custom user selected CSS template style (like wordpress visual editor)?

Tags: php, css, mysql, templates

I am making a diary app. I want users to be able to customize/style the skin of their journal e.g. covers/backgrounds/fonts/colors etc.

I want to create something like the wordpress theme editor that allows users to update the background color in real time:

[image]

Here is how style editor would look.

[image: UX]

For example if a user wants to set the writing area of the diary to a light yellow, how do I save that **color** into a custom CSS template and then render it again? Would I need to create a MySQL table just for style templates and have a row for color, background-color, etc... ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi Camilo, I have not tried anything yet, because I don't have a clue about how to approach the issue, the closest hint I have had is using CSS variables but they don't appear to have wide browse support yet!!

Comment: Use PHP to generate dynamic css https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/ so you can generate a dynamic css per user on the fly.

Comment: Interesting Raymond, thanks for the link.

Comment: I am working on something similar, are you going to store values per DOM element or for the whole page as a total? A simple implementation of color changing can be found here prodev.site/admin (click the logo to open the menu and from the settings you can quickly change page color). Perhaps creating a json settings file (per user), having the values of the colors,font etc to store to database would be a good idea. You could then pass the JSON to some javascript functions that will make the appropriate changes and complete the `magic`.

Comment: @Peter this is a great idea, I am going to post an answer that makes use of JSON, brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a working prototype here in case anyone is interested.

**How it works**

I am storing my template data as an array of JSON objects:

```
template: [
    {selector: '.notepad-container', property: 'background-image', value: null},
    {selector: '.notepad', property: 'background-image', value: null},
    {selector: '.notepad', property: 'font-size', value: null},
    {selector: '.notepad', property: 'font-family', value: null},
]
```

When a user wants to customise the style of the page they open the style editor. The selector and property that will be changed is stored in data attributes:

```
<div class="swatch render" data-selector=".notepad-container" data-property="background-image" style="background-image: url(img/background/asphalt.jpg);"></div>
```

So clicking this button will change the `background-image` of the `.notepad-container` class.

When they click to change a background the saveTemplate function is called and the selector and property is stored in the JSON object along with the background-image value:

```
saveTemplate: function(e){
    // get data-property and className attribute
    var selector = $(e.target).data('selector');
    var property = $(e.target).data('property');
    // where selector and property are same change model value
    var template = model.template;
    for (var i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
        if (template[i].selector === selector && template[i].property === property) {
            template[i].property = $(e.target).data('property');
            model.template[i].value = $(e.target).css(property);
            view.renderTemplate(model.template); // render json template
            return;
        }
    }
},
```

The template json data is passed to the `renderTemplate(model.template)` method which renders the changes.

```
renderTemplate: function(template){
    // json
    for (var i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
        if (template[i].value !== null) {
            $(template[i].selector).css(template[i].property, template[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

When the save button is pressed the template is stored in the associated 'table' in a text field called `template`.

here is a working demo: https://codepen.io/jethazelhurst/pen/vWWrrv

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to explain how to deal with your issue without knowing your complete environment and complete use-case. I assume, by your tags, that you use PHP to fetch your pages using the Laravel framework.

Now, you have several ways of doing what you are asking. But all ways reduce to one thing : how are you willing to manage persistence ?

Basically, you want users being able to "save" variables (in your case a variable like say "background_cover" or something similar) so that they can get a better visual experience or for tuning colors etc...

There are a lot of ways to store a variable, here are some of the most commonly used as of 2017:

- LocalStorage: you basically store a `background_color = yellow` into each user's browser. This is cool as it's easy to implement, but it is quite not the best way to persist data. If the user clear its cache: he's gonna lose the data... simple as that. I would suggest you go this route first, and evolves to other methods if you need more persistence. Also, don't forget the variable is stored in user's browser, this means it is not shareable to any other user later: it's private.
- On-Demand storage: A pretty good solution nowadays, given the cloud being more reliable each day. I would first go to on-demand solutions like Firebase by Google. It just let you send REST commands to save or retrieve whatever... and even using real-time capabilities. It's reliable. It's scalable. It's used by big names. Hard to do better for this little investment in time and money. You can use it using any technology able to send a `/POST` or `/GET` request like PHP does. You just need a thin client to better manipulate these requests and make sure they are always handled (supported by old internet explorer or mobile browsers...). One of those thin clients I'd recommend is `axios` and from what I know it is supported by Laravel. This is clearly the path I would suggest you if LocalStorage is not a good fit for your use-case.
- NoSQL databases: MongoDB and the likes are databases that are not really databases in the pure sense of it. Rather you could CONCEPTUALLY think them as an infinite notepad where you would write and read from as needed. Obviously it's not that simple but you get the point. They are quite fast and reliable for production persistence. There may be connectors for you to plug them somewhat easily into Laravel so that you could run some commands against it in a few hours of learning curve. Be carefull, most of NoSQL solution are more "Javascript-oriented" so you can get lost in your way. Nevertheless, it's a rather good approach to build a big app though it is not designed just to store 1 or 2 things, rather it is better at modeling relationships between data. But well, due to its popularity I'd say developers overused it for other purposes.
- Relational Database: Mysql, PostGreSql etc... are databases that uses SQL to store and retrieve entries. Clearly, it has a lot of performance behind the scenes but you should be warned that it also envolves A LOT of resources before you can just say "store this please". Most of the time it implies you installing the database on a server (which you should maintain as well...), learn SQL (quite easy but it's still something), and figure out how to model your data (primary keys, indexes etc...) then gather a solution able to connect the database to your PHP application so that you can run some SQL commands against it. 
  Clearly, this is not a "plug-n-play" solution: if you don't know it yet, clear yourself 50 hours of time just to be able to run a working SQL command from your app, or hire someone.
  This would be the LAST thing i'd recommend in quite any case. SQL Databases or RDBMS are better at retrieving huge data, I think it's a non-sense to go this route just for two variables.

Let me know if this answer is ok for you.

**EDIT**

After seeing some other replies, I am wondering what level of depth is asked. I originally thought the question "How do I store..." like a broader workflow explanation. If really the need is to have real code to persist data, I would say this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171190/how-to-store-data-to-database-in-laravel-5-2).

Now the whole procedure depends on the architecture already available but to stick with my proposition using [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) it all boils down to :

- register to firebase
- generate a private API key in Firebase
- create an API endpoint named say `/POST/user/preferences` in Firebase that will store "selected_color" (and other variables if needed)
- create an HTML page to authenticate a user using Firebase (by email, facebook or whatever)
- create an HTML page with a form that matches the options to give to the user (here a color switch for example)
- Create a workflow to serve login-page first, then authorize the user to go to the "color selection" form if the login/password is ok.
- Let the user pick his favorite color
- Make the user submit the form (click on SAVE)
- `/POST` the form data (including the API_KEY + USER_ID + SELECTED_COLOR) using `axios` to the firebase endpoint API

Done.

Now, whenever the user returns back to the page, you want to display the selected color back to its interface. For this, the procedure would look like:

- Make the user login using Firebase
- before fetching the relevant page, you want to retrieve back the variables you previously stored in Firebase using `axios` by requesting the endpoint with a `/GET` method.
- Once you have the data loaded in a PHP variable, you can update your CSS accordingly by generating a new CSS file based on the variables from your PHP server
- Then you can send the page to the user with relevant variables already plugged-in

Once again, we don't have enough input to gather the conditions into giving a specific answer to the problem.

Now I don't think StackOverflow is a good fit to make a whole tutorial on how to implement those steps one by one. Either the question is too broad and please fill in another more specific question about the exact part that is blocking/buggy/not understood... or you may look for some more detailed tutorials on Laravel/PHP. I can suggest this [video series](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017) (I have no links with this site whatsoever) on the matter: they are of very good quality (I used them to learn Vue.js which could also serve as a front-end framework for PHP) and will surely lead you to your desired use-case. 
If not, please edit the question to the exact step you need.
:)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give users the ability to style a few HTML elements on different sections of your website, the simplest implementation is the following:

1) Create table `users_styles` with fields:

```
id (INT), user_id (INT), section_id (INT), value (VARCHAR 1000).
```

The `value` field will contain a string with the values of styles in the JSON format. Don't forget about indexes.

2) Add constants of the style types in your PHP class, for example:

```
class UserStyle extends Model {

    const JOURNAL_COVER = 1;
    const FONT_NAME = 2;
    const FONT_SIZE = 3;
    const PAGE_THEME = 4;
    const PAD_THEME = 5;
    const BACKGROUND_COLOR = 6;
    // ...
}
```

Constants for sections:

```
class SiteSection extends Model {

    const MAIN = 1;
    const BLOG = 2;
    const CALENDAR = 3;
    // ...
}
```

3) Select types and values for the current user with the next query:

```
SELECT value
FROM users_styles
WHERE user_id = (int)$currentUserId
      AND section_id = (int)SiteSection::MAIN
```

You'll get a string like this:

```
$userStyles = {"1":"sand.jpg","2":"water.jpg","3":"fire.jpg","4":"#EFEFEF","5":"Lora","6":"17px"};
```

After `json_decode($userStyles, true);` it will contain the next values:

```
[
    1=>'sand.jpg',
    2=>'water.jpg',
    3=>'fire.jpg',
    4=>'#EFEFEF',
    5=>'Lora',
    6=>'17px'
];
```

4) Insert styles as internal styles in the corresponding section template with the selected data. For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: "<?= $userStyles[UserStyle::FONT_NAME] ?>", serif !important;
    font-size: <?= $userStyles[UserStyle::FONT_SIZE] ?>px !important;
    background-color: #<?= $userStyles[UserStyle::BACKGROUND_COLOR] ?> !important;
}

#journal-cover {
    background-image: url("<?= $currentUserStylesFilesDirPath.$userStyles[UserStyle::JOURNAL_COVER] ?>") !important;
}

#pad-theme {
    background-image: url("<?= currentUserStylesFilesDirPath.$userStyles[UserStyle::PAD_THEME] ?>") !important;
}
<style>
```

This rules will rewrite all relevant rules for the styles of the `body`, `#journal-cover` and `#pad-theme` elements.

Answer (score 1):

In Framework7 you can change the theme of the page with a function. I am not entirely sure what you are asking but from my understanding of your question: you can create a function that stores the user theme in LocalStorage. On page load you can read LocalStorage and apply the theme.

Another option would be, as you said in your question, storing this in a database.

If this is not what you are asking please correct me and I will edit or remove my answer.